# youtube_player_flutter and cached_network_image is not working in release apk

Tags: flutter, package, release, youtube-player-flutter, release-apk

I am using youtube_player_flutter and cached_network_image packages in flutter project they are working properly in debug mode but when i create apk using command `flutter build apk` and install it on the phone(android) it is not working and showing blank screen.
I have added permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` as mentioned in some answers but still it is not working with me

I am using

- Flutter 3.10.4
- youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.2
- cached_network_image: ^3.2.3